# Index reset needed when adding Crawl Component + CrawlDB?

Tags: 2010, crawl, searchserviceapplication

I've added a second crawl component and a second CrawlDB to my Search Service Application in SP 2010. The topology is online where the second crawl component is attached to the new CrawlDB.

Do I need to make an index reset or any other configuration to make the new crawl active and working in parallel with first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont to reset the index if you just want new content coming to this component. But if you want to divide the content equally then **Reset the Index and perform a Full Crawl.**

Or if you see any issue after adding new crawl DB i.e crawling on content source not completed etc.then you need a index reset followed by full crawl.